# Xamarin VS Windows - IPhone does not show up

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio for Windows and I have a Xamarin Forms app for Android and iOS. I mostly test physically on Android (since that is much easier) and I have tested on an IPhone as well about a year ago, which worked fine (without a mac). Now I plugged it in again and it doesn't work anymore: the IPhone does not show up in the debugging list.

I have:

- Apple Developer account and I'm connected with this account from Visual Studio
- Identifier for Bundle
- Profile (created by VS itself, with Type 'Development')

What am I missing here? I haven't added the provisioning profile in my solution, is that something that needs to be done? Am I missing another step?

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the exact breakdown on how to setup and get started with your iOS solution, follow Microsoft's [Xamarin iOS on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/) guide.

The tl;dr though is: you absolutely need a Mac to run a Xamarin iOS project, even on windows. I do not know how you had your project setup last time, however this has been the case since Xamarin's debut. Although, you could also just have access to a Mac through network connection instead of having a physical Mac. Without a physical device, you can use the Mac's ios simulator. If you are planning on using a physical iphone though, said device needs to be plugged into the Mac and not the windows machine. Later MacOS do support wireless connections of trusted devices, but it is still a wireless connection from the iphone to the mac (needing to be on the same network).